# Why is my function (when called) always returned as undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function for a web-based game I am designing, but whenever I call this function, it returns as undefined.

```js
function getRnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getOttomanRival() {
  return this.getRnd(1, 3)
  if (ottoman.rival == 1) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Mamluks"
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 2) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Delhi"
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 3) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Timurids"
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var ottoman = {
      rival: getOttomanRival()
    }
    document.GetElementById("ottomanRival").innerHTML = ottoman.rival()
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="ottomanRival"></p>
```

Comment: myFuncion() should placed outside the getOttomanRival()

Comment: Since `myFunction()` is defined inside `getOttomanRival()`, it's only accessible inside that scope.

Comment: The code you've provided does not behave the way you describe in the question. It throws an error.

Comment: @Quentin I think that's what he's saying, he just worded it poorly. He meant the function name is undefined, not that the call returns undefined.

Comment: This is littered with syntax errors. Even after you fix the one causing the current problem, it will just break for a different reason. It won't return undefined because it won't run at all.

Comment: You have a `return` statement as the first thing in the function, so nothing after that will be executed.

Comment: Why are you calling `this.getRnd()` instead of just `getRnd()`?

Comment: You probably meant to write `ottoman.rival = getRnd(1, 3);`

Comment: Because it is only known in the scope of the function **getOttomanRival()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This function (get Rand) looks good
function getRnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getOttomanRival() {
  return this.getRnd(1, 3) // if you return from here, none of the 
                           // following sentences will be executed
                           // Also you expect the rival name to be returned
                           // So store the random number in a variable
                           // and use it in your if condition and return
                           // the rival name once its set.
                           // Also "this" is not required here

  if (ottoman.rival == 1) { // check the random number generated,
                            // not the rival name against 1
    var ottoman.rival = "Mamluks"; // there is no syntax that declares
                                   // a variable "ottoman.rival" "." is 
                                   // not a valid variable name
                                   // use a simple variable
                                   // This function doesn't even need to know about
                                   // the structure of final object
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 2) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Delhi"
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 3) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Timurids"
  } 

  // missing a closing } for getOttomanRival

  function myFunction() {
    var ottoman = {
      rival: getOttomanRival()
    }
    document.GetElementById("ottomanRival").innerHTML = ottoman.rival() 
       // you probably meant "ottoman.rival"
       // without "()" as rival holds the result of `getOttomanRival()"
       // which is a string and not a function
  }
}
```

```js
function getRnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getOttomanRival() {
  var x = getRnd(1, 3),
    rival;
  if (x == 1) {
    rival = "Mamluks"
  }
  if (x == 2) {
    rival = "Delhi"
  }
  if (x == 3) {
    rival = "Timurids"
  }
  return rival;
}

function myFunction() {
  var ottoman = {
    rival: getOttomanRival()
  };
  document.getElementById("ottomanRival").innerHTML = ottoman.rival;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="ottomanRival"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `myFunction` is undefined is because it is wrapped inside another function `getOttomanRival()`

as @hriziya said, you could separate the functions like this

```
function getRnd(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getOttomanRival() {
  return this.getRnd(1, 3)
  if (ottoman.rival == 1) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Mamluks"
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 2) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Delhi"
  }
  if (ottoman.rival == 3) {
    var ottoman.rival = "Timurids"
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  var ottoman = {
    rival: getOttomanRival()
  }
  document.GetElementById("ottomanRival").innerHTML = ottoman.rival()
}
```

Or if you still need to keep the function nested, you could call it in your HTML like this:

```
<button onclick="(new getOttomanRival()).myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Provided `myFunction()` is updated like this

```
this.myFunction = function() {
  var ottoman = {
    rival: getOttomanRival()
  }
  document.GetElementById("ottomanRival").innerHTML = ottoman.rival()
}
```